# HTML Dropdown Menu remove white space between LI element

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm using image as dropdownlist items and found that there are unnecessary white space in between each of the element and hence wondering if it's possible to remove all of the white spaces

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="demo.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id='wrap'>
        <div id="clickable_div">MENU</div>
            <div id="nav_menu">
                <ul class="dropDown">
                    <li><img src="ori_12.png"></li>
                    <li><img src="ori_12.png"></li>
                    <li><img src="ori_12.png"></li>
                    <li><img src="ori_12.png"></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
<script>
        $('#wrap').mouseover( function(){
            $('#nav_menu').slideDown();
        })
        $('#wrap').mouseleave( function(){
            $('#nav_menu').slideUp();
        });

    </script>
</html>
```

And below is my **Demo.css**:

```
#clickable_div {width:166px; background-color:#9c9c9c;}
*{margin:0; padding:0}
#nav_menu{width:166px; height:auto; background-color:#CCC;display:none;}

#wrap{ width:166px }
```

Comment: Does your HTML include a `DOCTYPE`? If not you'll be working in "Quirks Mode", which is mainly there for compatibility with old web applications written for IE5, which means that getting CSS to do something predictable across browsers is not a fun task. Put the HTML5 `<!DOCTYPE html>` up top (before the opening `<html>` tag) and every modern browser will behave in roughly the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <style>
    li{
        display: block;
        border: 0px;
    }
</style>
```

add this style hope it will work

Comment: I think `border:0px` is not necessary, thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without jsfiddle but I would add display:block; to images in li..